# Newton Method in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, newtons-method

I am trying to use the scipy.newton method to optimize in a pandas dataframe.

First, my dataframe creation is below. 
Second, create the function Px. 
Third, create another function YieldCalc where I use scipy.newton to optimize to find the value for Rate such that Px = 0. Then I am trying to add that value to a new column 'Yield' but get the following error. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
from scipy import *
import scipy
import timeit   
#In:
#Creating Dataframe
df = DataFrame(list([100,2,34.1556,9,100]))
df = DataFrame.transpose(df)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'Face',1:'Freq',2:'N',3:'C',4:'Mkt_Price'})
df2= df
df = concat([df, df2])
df

#Out:
Face  Freq    N          C  Mkt_Price
100    2     34.1556     9    100
100    2     34.1556     9    100


#In:
Face = df['Face']
Freq = df['Freq']
N = df['N']
C = df['C']
Mkt_Price = df['Mkt_Price']


def Px(Rate):
    return Mkt_Price - (Face * ( 1 + Rate / Freq ) ** ( - N ) + ( C / Rate ) * ( 1 - (1 + ( Rate / Freq )) ** -N ) )

def YieldCalc():
    return scipy.optimize.newton(Px, .1, tol=.0001, maxiter=100)
df['Yield'] = YieldCalc()
```

Error/Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-f4961d3f817b> in <module>()
     12 def YieldCalc(Rate):
     13     return scipy.optimize.newton(Px, .1, tol=.0001, maxiter=100)
---> 14 df['Yield'] = YieldCalc(.05)

<ipython-input-89-f4961d3f817b> in YieldCalc(Rate)
     11 
     12 def YieldCalc(Rate):
---> 13     return scipy.optimize.newton(Px, .1, tol=.0001, maxiter=100)
     14 df['Yield'] = YieldCalc(.05)

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.pyc in newton(func, x0, fprime, args, tol, maxiter, fprime2)
    145         q1 = func(*((p1,) + args))
    146         for iter in range(maxiter):
--> 147             if q1 == q0:
    148                 if p1 != p0:
    149                     msg = "Tolerance of %s reached" % (p1 - p0)

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    674         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    675                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 676                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    677 
    678     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Does adding `.values` to your columns (as in `Mkt_price.values`) fix the error? Iirc, standard boolean operations with pandas dataframes are not the same as with numpy matrices.

Comment: Just tried it. Did not work.

Comment: Also, if you insert 'df['Yield'] = Px(.05)', it creates the new column with the Px() for that Rate. So i think it is something to do with the YieldCalc formula.

Comment: First, "Did not work" is not a useful statement for further investigation. Second, if your method doesn't work with `numpy` matrices either, it's not a `pandas` specific problem. Try stripping it down until it works and figure out what exactly causes the problem. Perhaps restating the simpler problem (in the context of `numpy`/`scipy` will get your additional responses under those tags.

Comment: This was also rather a preemptive comment. You may still get useful feedback the way this is stated, but this is not a very typical use case within `pandas`. Within `numpy`, surely.

Comment: Noted - I am new new poster so I thank you for your patience. Will restate and try to make more clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the trick here is what you get back from `df['Face']` is not a single value or even an array.  They're still tied to pandas.

You can, as suggested, start getting access the raw data by way of `.values` and feed that into a function.

Alternatively, pandas data frames have a `.apply` method that will allow you to take a function and run it over every row or col.

I put the following at the end of the code that you posted (commenting out the offending line first)

```
def Foo(thing, Rate):
    return thing[0]*Rate

df['Yield'] = df.apply(Foo,axis=1,args=(0.1,))
df.head()
```

In here the `.apply` method will pass the function `Foo` all of the entries in a given row of `df` as a series, and the argument `0.1` as well.  The axis specification is what sets this to be done by row (`axis=0` will do the col).

Just reorganize `Px` to accept 'Rate' and the series of values from `df` (in that order). Then have `YieldCalc` accept that series as well.  Also, you'll need to use an `args=` entry in the `newton` call to pass that series of values to `Px` when it hunts for zeros.

The flow should be:

`.apply` makes a series `thing` out of a row from `df` and passes it to `YieldCalc`. `YieldCalc` runs `newton` on `Px(Rate,thing)' to find`Rate` returns 0.  Then all of those results get put into your new Yield col.